# URL encoding "+" character

Tags: javascript, html, url, encoding, codeigniter-3

I have an application where the users can upload files. So filenames can contain characters like **+**. I do not want to change the filenames and eliminate these chars.
Other users can download these files. I implemented this by creating a form with a link (action) to the file and open it in a new tab.
For simple filenames this works, e.g. **filename.docx**. But for e.g. **filename+suffix.docx** I receive a file not found error (because of the **+**).
I have already used `encodeURIComponent("filename+suffix.docx")` but it did not work.

Any suggestions? Thanks in advance.

Comment: you may have to double-encode, e.g. `+` -> `%2b` -> `%252b`

Comment: `encodeURIComponent("filename+suffix.docx")` is correct. If it doesn't work then either you are breaking it before putting it in the URL or there is a problem with your server.

Comment: @MarcB: Double-encoding did not work.

Comment: then show exactly how/where you're using that encoded string.

Comment: @AlexK.: I insert the URL (http ://myurl/folder/filename%2Bsuffix.docx) into action property of form tag and submit it with JavaScript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Quentin for your hint. I found the solution here: http://www.ifinity.com.au/Blog/EntryId/60/404-Error-in-IIS-7-when-using-a-Url-with-a-plus-sign-in-the-path